# How to achieve this subquery in laravel , I want add to one field in result as a flag value

Tags: php, laravel

Hi everyone I'am new to laravel  I want to get result of  all posts and also want flag that logged user has liked that post or not as like instagram posts (if logged  user has liked the post then flag postIsLiked as 1 so i can display like heart icon as red else black heart(not liked) )

**MY MAIN TABLES AND THEIR RESP FEILDS ARE AS FOLLOWS :**

1. posts = id(PK), user_id(FK),post_caption,...
2. users= id(PK), username,fname,lname,....
3. post_likes = id(PK),post_id(FK),user_id(FK),

**And this is the query that I have tried , I dont know how can I achieve this**

```
$postData = DB::table('posts')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('user_profile', 'user_profile.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    // ->leftJoin('post_likes' , 'posts.id' '=','post_likes.post_id')
    ->select( 'posts.id as postId' ,'users.*','posts.post_caption','posts.post_media','posts.created_at','user_profile.profile_pic','post_likes.id')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Please help me in this , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to take the leftJoin of the posts on the likes of the current user.
I've tested this query and it should work:

```
$postData = DB::table('posts')
        ->leftJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftJoin('user_profiles', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'user_profiles.id')
        ->leftJoin('post_likes', function ($join) {
            $join->on('posts.id', '=', 'post_likes.post_id')
                ->where('post_likes.user_id', '=', Auth::id());
        })
        ->select('adjust the columns accordingly', 'post_likes.id as likeId')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

If `likeId == NULL` then the current user hasn't liked the post, else it will have a value. Using this id will make it simpler to dislike the Post by deleting the like.

Just an observation: we are joining the Profiles on the id of the User, it is not obvious that the ids will be the same.

Comment: hey @nicola thank you very much for your answer. I accepted it as a answer

Answer (score 1):

Kindly replace it with this query. I added **IF condition to check for the postIsLiked flag.**

```
$postData = DB::table('posts')
    ->leftJoin('post_likes' , 'posts.id' '=','post_likes.post_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'post_likes.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('user_profile', 'user_profile.id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('posts.id as postId', 'users.*', 'posts.post_caption', 'posts.post_media', 'posts.created_at', 'user_profile.profile_pic', 'post_likes.id', DB::raw('IF (post_likes.user_id = '.auth()->user()->id.', "1", "0") as postIsLiked'))
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Let me know the results.

Comment: hey @vivek thank you for your answer it also working , but there is one problem if user haven't liked the post the user data is getting null , otherwise ok, thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll improve the answer. Happy Coding :)